# RabbitMQ metrics not found with prometheus

Tags: java, c, rabbitmq

I have been trying to get RabbitMQ's metrics to use it with prometheus and the query is "rabbitmq_identity_info" that I have used but no success. But I can see some other RabbitMQ's related metrics. I have spent a lot of time for this issue.but couldn't fix. Can you please anyone help me?

this issue got resolved. But still i need more information on how can i get the queue name and count from rabbitmq? i cant see any related metrics for that.
Can you please anyone help me on this?

Comment: Did you check if the corresponding exporter is running on your host?

Comment: yes it's running. only some of the metrics are not visible. and is there any namespace variable used in rabbitmq exporter?

Comment: Have you configured your rabbitmq exporter to include "exclude_metrics" in order to exclude few metrics from getting scraped.

You can follow the below docs for more reference:

https://github.com/kbudde/rabbitmq_exporter

https://github.com/kbudde/rabbitmq_exporter/blob/main/config.example.json

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [rabbitmq-exporter](https://github.com/kbudde/rabbitmq_exporter) or the [prometheus_rabbitmq_exporter](https://github.com/deadtrickster/prometheus_rabbitmq_exporter) plugin?

If you are using the first one, probably you won't be able to see it, because it is available just from the plugin.

Comment: I was using rabbitmq-exporter. So it didnt work. now it works. Thanks

this issue got resolved. But still I need more information on how can i get the queue name and count from rabbitmq? i cant see any related metrics for that. Can you please anyone help me on this?

Comment: we had the same problem, and it was just a permission problem.
Try to get that information by hand using the same user than your monitoring system.
We finally added read permissions for everything to that user. Something like:
`rabbitmqctl set_permissions <USER> "" "" ".*"`

Comment: I use prometheus_rabbitmq_exporter and I have the same problem, how do you solve the issue ? I cant see namespace in the rabbitmq_identity_info